# How can I use diff lib in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to make simple compare between two strings in react-native. For now i am using this [lib](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) . It is simple to use so my code so far :

```
  const CustomText = (props) => {
    const text1 = props.userText;
    const text2 = props.currectText;
    const diff = diffChars(text2, text1);
    return (
      <Text>
        {diff.map((part, value) => {
          // green for additions, red for deletions
          // grey for common parts
          const color = part.added ? "green" : part.removed ? "red" : "grey";
          return (
            <Text key={value} style={{ color: color }}>
              {part.value}
            </Text>
          );
        })}
      </Text>
    );
  };
```

And i expected to get something like that [image]. But for now it doesn't print anything on my screen ? Maybe i return something wrong .

Comment: How and where are you calling `test()`?

Comment: You have to change `forEach` to `map` to transform the `diff` array. Like this: `const coloredDiff = diff.map((part)...`. And then render return it using `return coloredDiff `

Comment: Replace `.forEach` with `.map`

Comment: I have changed my function with component. Is it too complex that i made it ? Also thanks for help !

Comment: Does it work? The complexity is not too much.